# helm push fails to push helm chart to specific ECR repo

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to push helm chart to ECR_REPO in a ECR registry,
command is:

helm push ./$chart_name-$HELM_VERSION.tgz oci://$HELM_ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPO:$HELM_VERSION

and it fails like below.

its thowing error like:
Error: failed to do request: Post "https://123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/parentfolder/project-chart/blobs/uploads/": EOF

where is it works to the base of registry with below command:

helm push ./$chart_name-$HELM_VERSION.tgz oci://$HELM_ECR_REGISTRY:$HELM_VERSION

Comment: does $ECR_REPO repo exist in ECR?

Comment: yes, it exists. @Raghu

Comment: @Raghu: it works for helm chart with apiversion:v1 but it fails when used helm chart with apiVersion:v2, which adds 'v2' in the helm push action: 
example you can see v2 after ECR in path:
https://123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/parentfolder/project-chart/blobs/uploads/

Comment: Issue is fixed, Actually, as you said @Raghu, ECR repo was not created from the script. There was a typo with the similar name which was causing the confusion.